# Implimentation using Array and linklist

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, stack, queue

What is the use of learning same data structure first using linklist and then using array??

Like in the case of stack and queue.

If I learn only implimentation of linklist in these data structure is this sufficient for competative programming??

Comment: You're not learning stack and queue.  You're learning about linked lists, and learning about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Learning the two implementations tells us the various benefits and disadvantages of the various data structures. Coz when you are learning new data structures the more you can relate to simpler data structures the more easily you can understand and grasp the similarities and subtle changes between them.

Moreover it never hurts to have multiple implementations.

Comment: That I know but is there any advantage of using array based implimentation in programming??

Comment: @MohdArsalan Yes. Arrays can often be faster and use less memory than linked lists. For example, if you know that your queue can never contain more than some relatively small number of items, then a fixed array implementation will be easier to write, faster, and use less memory than a linked list implementation. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-vs-array/ for more information and examples.